# Is 羞辱 a kind of verb after which you put two objects?

Tags: verbs, complement

> 他于是决定羞辱猫一番

Is 羞辱 a kind of verb after which you put two objects (I think we call it "object and complement")? I mean, a verb like 给, where you can for example say 我给你(o1)我的书(o2).

I don't quite understand if I should take 一番 from this sentence as a noun meaning "a word/ a sentence" or what. This is my main concern, in fact.

I'm sorry for asking two questions instead of one, but I think they're connected and the answer to the first one influences the answer to the second one.

Comment: "他于是决定羞辱猫一番" should be "他于是决定羞辱(這)猫一番" because just saying  '猫' the object would be indefinite, it can be any cat. It would be worse if the object is 人 instead of 這人

Comment: @TangHo The sentence is ok as-is.  Which 猫 is referred to can be figured according to context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chinese grammar, 一番 here is 数量短语.  (not sure the correct translation of 数量短语, but literally it could be *a numeral phrase*).  一 is 数词(numeral) and 番 is 量词(measure word), so 一番 together is 数量短语.

One of the functions of 数量短语 is ***to work as a complement***.  E. g. 看一次.  where 看 is a verb and 一次 is a complement.

By the same token, your example 羞辱猫一番 is understood grammatically as: 羞辱(verb)猫(object)一番(complement for the verb 羞辱).

Answer (score 1):

- In "這一番羞辱" (this *one* humiliation), 一番 is the counting word and classifier for the noun 羞辱
- In "羞辱他一番" (to humiliate him *once*)  一番 is the counting word and verb classifier for the verb 羞辱

*A verb classifier is for counting the number of a verb occurred, for example, 走兩回 (go two times); 斬一刀 (hack once)*

As a verb, 羞辱 does take objects

Example:

當眾羞辱他 - Humiliate him in public

這番蠢話羞辱了他自己 - These foolish words humiliated himself

Answer (score 1):

No, there is only one object, 貓.

一番, an adverb, literally means "once". Implicitly it bears the meaning of "completely", "to the degree of satisfaction".